# Missing SignalR dll when publish web api to folder

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I have a ASP.NET 6.0 API using SignalR.

Everything is OK on localhost. But when I publish project to folder by using Visual Studio 2022, I do not see SignalR's .dll file in the artifacts.

Is there any wrong when I publish project?

Comment: How do you publish? When you test the site, do you get an error?